# Erro de chamada no arquivo js do Bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Quando acesso o console do navegador ele me gera o seguinte erro:
[image]
[image]

As funções do Bootstrap como o `tooltip` funcionam normalmente mesmo com o tal erro, estou chamando o jQuery antes do Bootstrap como na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque desse erro e como resolvê-lo?

Comment: E onde está o arquivo do require.js ? rs

Comment: Esse arquivo na existe na arquitetura de pastas do bootstrap na documentação também não fala nada sobre ele, será que esqueceram? kkkkk

Comment: Mas por que você quer carregar todo js separado? rs vai até demorar para carregar o teu site/sistema

Comment: Esse aquivo faz parte do bootstrap [Print das Pastas](http://i.imgur.com/5kwGI2O.png)